# Flume. Strip all tags from syslogudp source

Tags: nginx, flume, syslog, rsyslog

I am using apache-flume with syslogudp source.
I set following into flume.conf:

```
agent.sources.r1.type = syslogudp
agent.sources.r1.port = 5140
agent.sources.r1.host = localhost
agent.sources.r1.channels = c1
```

And following nginx.conf options:

```
access_log syslog:server=localhost,tag= ;
```

As result all my logs in sink (kafka topic) have 2 symbols in beginning. 
For example:

```
: 31.130.95.75  1472493421.911  80674   {flags}
```

Is there any way to cut off first colon and space symbols?

thanks

Comment: In my case nginx: in beginning！

nginx: 2016-08-27T18:21:59+08:00"14.88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Search and Replace Interceptor ( https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#search-and-replace-interceptor )

You can use the interceptor to edit event bodies using regular expressions.

In your case, the modified config would look like this:

```
agent.sources.r1.type = syslogudp
agent.sources.r1.port = 5140
agent.sources.r1.host = localhost
agent.sources.r1.channels = c1


agent.sources.r1.interceptors = search-replace
agent.sources.r1.interceptors.search-replace.type = search_replace

agent.sources.r1.interceptors.search-replace.searchPattern = ^.*:
agent.sources.r1.interceptors.search-replace.replaceString =
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing to interceptors.  I changed regex a little, but not too far from your version. Actually I want to remove colon + space from beginning, so right regexp is ^:.

Comment: @Samriang: Thank you for the info. This might be very useful for other people encountering this issue

Answer (score -1):

In my case
nginx: in beginning！

nginx: 2016-08-27T18:21:59+08:00"14.88.133.152"14.88.133.152"GET"api.xxx.com"/mobile/member/user/bind/push"HTTP/1.1"-"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.2; HTC 802t Build/LRX22G)"1141"200"370"31"127.0.0.1:9000"0.00"-"-"0.082"0.080"-"g7/rxU9nj++0/E6pn7/m0EOZ7WEiWtJOHFePbHgVG8mILk0J2IDVdjQ1R4dr75h2etJxxv6VJ+z5Nk/Kh5Us/bt8NgyhF7STUT3mxFaaO7LmI2DeP/7YKRwdPcy0SOw0yRo0GrMOBRG0KWbbJbnDn4mURXpx4dkDbbSOt6q4LIbKY4qC+nslbsPM9iZknSEhtnlK1NhvbeH28DgVjz7yGOKYEVZ2wlP9mikwUtqUgl"app=a-angejia;av=4.0.1;ccid=1;gcid=;ch=B48;lng=;lat=;net=WIFI;p=android;pm=Android-HTC 802t;osv=5.0.2;dvid=35586705393334084:7a:88:7f:0b:18"-"4000"2000"10"28280

Comment: You can remove 'nginx' in beginning with setting tag=  for log configuration in nginx.conf. But in my case I need colon and space to be removed.